# Xamarin memory leak when swapping pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory-leaks

I am having a lot of difficulty with memory leaks using Xamarin. There is one set in particular that I am struggling with. To illustrate this leak, I created the simplest possible program that simply switches between two pages. The code is as follows:

App.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    [assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    namespace MemoryLeak
    {
        public partial class App : Application
        {
            public static App m_app;

            MainPage[] pages = new MainPage[2];

            public void SetPage(int idx)
            {
                MainPage page = pages[idx % 2];

                GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{1}:mem={0}", System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true), idx));

                page.ShowMemoryUse();

                MainPage = page;
            }

            public App()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                m_app = this;

                pages[0] = new MainPage(0);
                pages[1] = new MainPage(1);

                SetPage(0);
            }

            protected override void OnStart()
            {
                // Handle when your app starts
            }

            protected override void OnSleep()
            {
                // Handle when your app sleeps
            }

            protected override void OnResume()
            {
                // Handle when your app resumes
            }
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MemoryLeak"
                 x:Class="MemoryLeak.MainPage">

        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <Label x:Name="myText" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button Text="Next" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace MemoryLeak
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            int m_id;

            public MainPage(int id)
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                m_id = id;
            }

            public void ShowMemoryUse()
            {
                myText.Text = string.Format("{1}: {0}", System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true), m_id);
            }

            void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                App.m_app.SetPage(m_id == 0 ? 1 : 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now if I run this program under UWP and click repeatedly on the 'Next' button, I see that the memory usage increases without bounds. If I use the Performance Profiler, I also see numerous objects which are never freed. For example, clicking the 'Next' button 40 times produces the following objects stranded:

- PropertyChangedEventHandler - 95 instances created
- EventHandler - 94 instances created
- ConditionalWeakTable - 72 instances created
- Container - 72 instances created
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PageRenderer [RCW] - 41 instances created
- Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.BackgroundTracker - 41 instances created
- RuntimeType - 360 instances created

And many more.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. Is this a problem with Xamarin? Should I not be swapping pages by assiging to 'MainPage'?

Thanks.

Comment: As a test, I changed the app so that I create a single ContentPage which is assigned to MainPage and not changed. I then change the views by altering ContentPage.Content. When I do this, I find that under UWP the memory leak seems to disappear. However when I run this on Android I still see a loss of around 5K bytes per cycle from page 0 to page 1 and back. Does garbage collection actually work for Xamarin?

Comment: ,I try your code, and it did increase all time. You said you change contentpage.content in uwp, the memory leak disappear, can you try to use navigation to swap pages in android?